# Establishing Memory in Parallel C++

Tags: c++, memory, parallel-processing

I have a problem whereby I want to test a parallel system against a non-parallel system.

In system 1 I establish the memory as such:

```
std::vector<double>* p_val_vec_main = new std::vector<double>(*mpStages);
std::vector<double>* p_val_vec_slave = new std::vector<double>(*mpStages-1);
std::vector<std::vector<double> >* p_mat_cache =
     new std::vector<std::vector<double> >(3, std::vector<double>());
```

These vectors are passed around, and used in an RAII system that is repeated, hence the pointers and new syntax.

In system 2 (the parallel system), I'm trying to establish the 3 vectors in parallel given there is no - presumed - overlap as such:

```
#pragma omp parallel
{
    std::vector<double>* p_val_vec_main = new std::vector<double>(*mpStages);
    std::vector<double>* p_val_vec_slave = new std::vector<double>(*mpStages-1);
    std::vector<std::vector<double> >* p_mat_cache =
    new std::vector<std::vector<double> >(3, std::vector<double>());
}
```

However the first time I go to reference 'p_val_vec_main' outside the pragma block, but inside the method where the pragma block is, on a valid element in system 2 I receive the error code:

```
error: 'p_val_vec_main' was not declared in this scope
```

Was wondering if anyone knew why this was happening? My only thoughts as to what this could be would be local/global clashes possibly.

Comment: When you say you "reference p_val_vec_main" on system 2, do you mean you literally refer to the variable you declared inside your `pragma omp parallel` block? Or are you saying you refer to a copy of that pointer that was "passed around" into your RAII  system?

Comment: Outside the pragma block, but in the method where the pragma block is @Edward

Comment: `new std::vector<...` is almost always a bad idea. That actually holds for all containers. Just use the container type directly. "Using RAII" is not a argument _for_ pointer, it's an argument _against_ pointers.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're having is that the `#pragma omp parallel` block, which you only use on System 2, creates an additional scope level (between the opening and closing braces) that hides the pointer variable `p_val_vec_main` (and the other variables) from any statements before and after it. This is a necessary part of using `omp parallel` because OpenMP internally converts the statements inside a `parallel` block into a function, so any variables declared inside that block become function-local.

If you want to initialize the vectors inside an `omp parallel` block but use them outside of it, you'll need to declare the pointers at a higher level scope, like this:

```
std::vector<double>* p_val_vec_main;
std::vector<double>* p_val_vec_slave;
std::vector<std::vector<double> >* p_mat_cache;
#pragma omp parallel
{
    p_val_vec_main = new std::vector<double>(*mpStages);
    p_val_vec_slave = new std::vector<double>(*mpStages-1);
    p_mat_cache =
    new std::vector<std::vector<double> >(3, std::vector<double>());
}
//p_val_vec_main can be used here
```

Answer (score 0):

Compiler error clearly describes the problem. `p_val_vec_main` declared in the block:

```
#pragma omp parallel
{
  std::vector<double>* p_val_vec_main = new std::vector<double>(*mpStages);
  // Other declarations skipped
}
```

You cannot access it out of this block. Read more about [Block scope here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/scope).

Comment: I understand scopes, but my question is regarding why it does this for a parallel scope. Additionally why would it skip the other declarations?

Comment: @Murphy'sLaw `#pragma omp parallel` defines a region that should be executed in parallel. This scope has the same visibility rules as other block scopes. So if your other logic is outside of this scope it cannot access variables defined there.

Comment: @Murphy'sLaw Was that helpful or you need more help? If this or any other answer has solved your question please consider upvoting and/or [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark.

Comment: Hi Nikita. Your answer made sense. Thanks for helping.